# how to stay at the same page location after this.form.submit()?

Tags: javascript

After I perform this.form.submit() onchange event it reloads the page and brings to the very top of the page. Is there a possible solution to be brought to the same page location I was before the js onchange call ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make an ajax call so that the page is not entirely reloaded (nor scrolled back).

Or you can use anchors to scroll to a specific `div`. To do so append `#theIdOfTheDiv` at the end of the redirection URL.

Comment: I don't need a redirect - I need to submit the form. and I cannot use ajax call for this instance

Comment: When I say "redirection page" I talk about the page that is displayed after form submission, it can be the same from where the submit was done. If this is in PHP for instance and you are not using redirection, then it is the URL specified in the action attribute on the form.

Answer (score 0):

Either use AJAX so the page doesn't reload, or change the action URL in your form to use a named anchor (`#something`) so it reloads to the corresponding anchor on the page.

Comment: No offense but what information does your answer add to the one I already posted 3 minutes before.

Comment: And by the way the action form URL is not necessarily the one you are redirected to .

Comment: @KayKay - I was writing up my answer that included two methods when you edited your at about the same time. And I have no idea what you mean in your second comment.

Comment: is there a way to jump to the bottom of the page upon onload event ?

Comment: @IevgeniiFedorenko - sure, you would need to use JavaScript and have a named anchor in the page where you want it to jump to.